# Dealing with lack of glDrawElementsBaseVertex in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I'm working on porting a Direct3D terrain renderer to Android and just learned that OpenGL did not have an equivalent to the BaseVertexIndex parameter of DrawIndexedPrimitive until version 3.2 introduced the glDrawElementsBaseVertex method. That method is not available in OpenGL ES.

The D3D terrain renderer uses a single, large vertex buffer to hold the active terrain patches in an LRU fashion. The same 16-bit indices are used to draw each patch.

Given the lack of a base vertex index offset in OpenGL ES, I can't use the same indices to draw each patch. Furthermore, the buffer is too large for 16-bit absolute indices. The alternatives I've identified are:

1. Use one VBO or vertex array per patch.
2. Use 32-bit indices and generate new indices for every block in the VBO.
3. Stop using indexing and replicate vertices as needed. Note that most vertices appear in six triangles. Switching to triangle strips could help, but still doubles the number of vertices.

None of these seem very efficient compared to what was possible in D3D. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Take a look at instancing, maybe? You can draw many instances of the same VBO with one call, and use `gl_instanceID` to treat them differently in shader code. Instancing is core in ES3 and a popular extension in ES2.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the exact data layout of your VBOs, but if your base vertex offset is not negative you can apply an offset when binding the VBO to the vertex attribute (glVertexAttribPointer).